# Windows Yeoman Generator Blank Directory

Tags: windows, yeoman, office-addins

I am currently working on a project that will require a add-in to MS Outlook. I am reading the documentation that shows the use of yeoman to do this but keep hitting the issue where yeoman is only creating a blank directory rather that a scaffolded project. I have the yo command and generator-office installed globally and run `yo office` to start the wizard.

At the end of the wizard is see  `Creating My Office Add-in add-in for Outlook using TypeScript and Taskpane at {path}\My Office Add-in` then i am returned to the cli prompt.

I am running NPM 6.14.8 and Node v12.19.0. Not sure what I am missing here

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to directory permissions. I created a new directory on my C:\ and now all is working.